# How can I print multiple copies with different text on the bottom of each page?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-2010

I have a fill-able form in Microsoft Word 2010 that is intended to replace an old carbon copy form.  I need it to print three copies of each form, but have a different footer on each page that indicates the department with which each copy corresponds.

Someone would fill out the form and hit "print" and it would print out three identical copies. However, the bottom of each copy would list a different department.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: pretty easy if you use the correct software https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ja7PLjXTAHw with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqv36MBn12k

Answer (score 3):

Use the "Mail Merge" feature.

In the Mail Merge wizard, select "Type a new list" and for each "Department" create a new entry.  In your footer, add your "Department Name" merge field.

Comment: This is pretty good but I have two issues:
1. This form is for lay users.  Is there anyway they can print it without having to go through the Mail Merge process?
2. This form needs to be distributed and the list of department saves in a separate file.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the form has a footer with 'dept 1' in it, I think that you could write a macro that offers the user a print button and then:

1. Prints the form
2. Edits the footer to read 'dept 2' and prints again
3. Edits the footer for 'dept 3' and prints again
4. Resets the footer back to 'dept 1' in case they want to print three copies again.

Comment: How would I do that.